# How to divide code into multiple .cpp files C++

Tags: c++

I want to create a function outside the main.cpp file
i've tried creating a header file but it doesn't work:

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include "other.h"
int main() {
    MyFunc();
}
```

**Other.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "other.h"
void MyFunc() {
    std::cout << "Ohai from another .cpp file!";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

**Other.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "other.cpp"
void MyFunc();
```

nor CPP, G++, GCC compiler work

[GCC Compiling error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnse1.png)
[Errors shown by vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojI8Y.png)

Comment: most likely a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files

Comment: Read the following manual [about linking](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-the-compiler-linker-and-libraries/)

Comment: Remove `#include "other.cpp"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - Compiling multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066437/c-compiling-multiple-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include a header file and not a C++ file.

And therefore, you need to remove:

```
#include "other.cpp"
```

from `other.h` & use the following command-line for compiling:

```
g++ -o output main.cpp other.cpp
```

You'll get it linked and then compiled, then everything should be working fine.

Comment: No, this is backwards. The implementation file should `#include` the header file; the header should not `#include` the implementation file. The problem here is misunderstanding the C++ compilation model. Each source file is separate, and gets compiled on its own. The resulting object files get linked and you have a program. You don't `#include` all your source files into one massive beast.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right. We must use `.h` or `.hpp` file, not a `cpp` in `#include`.

Comment: Much better! +1.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove #include "other.cpp" in header file.

Answer (score -1):

erase the line "#include "other.cpp" in your other.h and you will be fine...

Edit: you also need a header guard...

Comment: Could you please advice the explained solution of translation units, and linking.