# how would I compile multiple files in a folder?

Tags: c++

so, I have decided to completely write my game (turn based RPG) in C++.

I have seen other people on youtube create a folder with different cpp files and somehow they compile it all.

my question is, how would I compile multiple files in a folder?

if needed I am using MSYS.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: `g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp -o game.exe`. AFAIK PowerShell supports globs: `g++ *.cpp -o game.exe` should also work.

Comment: You might be interested in reading: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - Compiling multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066437/c-compiling-multiple-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using cmake

You can either write a makefile, which would contain all the files to be compiled in a folder or for a better management you can use cmake to compile all the files into a library and use them again.  By using cmake you can efficiently maintain and build a huge code base.

Lets say, your Main directory has the main.cpp file and inside it has a src folder which has all other files to be compiled ,

Then You can create a `CMakeLists.txt` file with following contents

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -std=c++14 ")
add_subdirectory(src)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main compiledLibrariesfrmSrcFolder)
```

Then Navigate inside your `src` directory to create one more CMakeLists.txt. This will control all the files that you need to compileand add to your main program.

```
add_library(compiledLibrariesfrmSrcFolder STATIC
a.cpp
b.cpp
c.cpp
d.cpp)
```

Else, you could also use `GLOB_RECURSE` to add all the .cpp files in that subdirectory

Once this is done, then you could create a new folder in your home directory and run the following
`mkdir build`

```
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

This compiles and generates your executable in the build folder.

Note : Just to elaborate more, The main reason to do this inside a build is because cmake creates lots of temp files during the process, To isolate them from your main code you will do the build inside the build directory.

`cmake ../` , Here the cmake accepts a parameter which is the location of the main `CMakeLists.txt` file. In our case it will be a directory before build. This creates the `MakeFile`  which has instructions to compile and link all the other necessary files.

`make` compiles and links the files and generates the executables.

Comment: CMake will also greatly help if you are to share your source code with others as you can generate project files for other compilers like mscv / Visual Studio or IDEs like XCode or qt-creator in addition to generating Makefiles.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I'll try this.