# Is there a way to automatically link and compile all the required files in g++

Tags: c++, g++

I am new to C++ and suppose I have three files `main.cpp`, `test.cpp` and `test.h`.
The `main.cpp` file includes the `test.h` header file.

Now to successfully compile the files I am using the following command:

```
g++ main.cpp test.cpp -o main.exe
```

Is there a way to only supply `main.cpp` and the compiler would automatically compile all the required files?

Thank you.

Comment: You could look at building a `Makefile`.

Comment: You want a build system. My personal favorite is DDS, but it's still in its infancy (not yet 1.0). Popular cross-platform ones are: CMake, Meson, Build2, Bazel. Makefiles are one of the most common, but they are trickier to set up correctly and harder to make cross-platform to non-Unix systems (e.g. Windows).

Comment: I wish there was something as simple, Bazel (https://bazel.build/) and Evoke (https://github.com/dascandy/evoke, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWOmkwv8N_U) promise that, but I never had the opportunity to try them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372416/how-would-i-compile-multiple-files-in-a-folder/67372615#67372615 Check this answer

Answer (score 0):

if you are using vs code u can download c/c++ extension by microsoft then u hit f6 it will compile all .cpp file on your directory and add f3 to help this will add super powers and allow it to fly. bc red bull gives u wings

Comment: try this it worked for me:
go to .vs folder on your project directory open task.json file and replace args with that piece of code ```
"args": [
                "-g3",
                "-Wall",
                "*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
```

Comment: @Prabodh and try again